# Need to modify an existing SSIS package?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have a SQL query which results 1 or 0(Based on input). I want to introduce one new DataFLow task in existing package in which DataFlow task has to execute if the query results 1 stating that Job has failed. If query result  0 it has to goto the next DataFlow Task? Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare a variable- say, iResult as int
2. On the control flow surface, place Execute SQL task.
3. Set your SQLStatement; say - Select 1 As MyResult.
4. Set Result Set to Single Row.
5. Go to Result Set section. Set Result Name to MyResult. Select User::iResult as variable name from the drop down.
6. Now, place your two DFTs on the control flow surface.
7. Join both of them to the Execute SQL task (two green lines) your worked on in the above steps.
8. Double-click on one of the precedence constraint. Set Evaluation Operation to Expression and constraint, Value to Success, and Expression to @iResult  == 0.
9. Repeat for the other one, and set Expression to @iResult == 1.

Ideally, you should use a boolean variable.That would pose a little bit of challenge. I will leave that as a tiny challenge for you and the next reader who lands up here. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response!!! Could you please be more specific on Point 6. Actually i need to place only one DFT. But you have mentioned two DFT. im bit confused!!!

Comment: If you don't mind, If you have any documentation for this type of operations(For creating Expressions) so that i could refer those in future. Actually iam very new to this SSIS. Im in learning phase.

Comment: Your main question here is: How do I implement a conditional split in the control flow? SSIS provides a conditional split task for the data flow, but for the control flow there is no such component. My example above shows how to devise the conditional split on the control surface. Once you have determined whether the value of the query was 0 or 1, you can connect them to whatever task you want to.  In my example, I chose DFT for both the scenarios. You can remove one of them and place - say - a script task and inside the script task you can have a message box display the job failed message.

Comment: Regarding the documentation... As a starter, which book have you bought? Because, almost any book on SSIS will cover this technique. You do not have any book, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026(v=sql.105).aspx. A good book that I would recommend: http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Microsoft-Integration-Services-Programmer/dp/0470247959.

Comment: Thank you Very much Anoop Verma !!! I need little more enhancively like, Can't we assign in one Execute SQL TASK that If Select command result is '1' then it will goto Failure Constraint and if it is '0' means it will goto success constraint?

Comment: As per the ur instructions i have done the task but it throws the following error: Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "SELECT     InterfaceName
FROM         dbo.LDMInteg..." failed with the following error: "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
Task failed: Checking Integrity Error log

Answer (score 0):

Do it another way. Use a SQL Comand to collect the the 1/0 and put into a variable.

Then use the variable to make a decision as to which data flow to execute.

Comment: Could you please how to make use of a variable with an example?

Comment: Please refer to my example. Follow the steps of the example to see where it takes you - the light bulb will turn on! ;-)